# Deploying snapshot not release using maven

Tags: git, maven, teamcity, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release artefacts from GIT to Nexus using maven  but it is creating snapshot instead of release

I am using following goal

clean install -B -U release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Dsettings.security=/home/artemisd/.m2/settings-security.xml -s Database/development/etc/build/.m2/settings.xml  --global-settings /home/artemisd/.m2/settings_git.xml

POM.XML looks like below

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.campus.fit.artemis</groupId>
<artifactId>database</artifactId>
<version>4.0.98-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>FIT Artemis Database module</description>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        <id>artemis-release-repo</id>
        <name>Artemis Release Repository</name>
        <url>
            https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-release/
        </url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        <id>artemis-snapshot-repo</id>
        <name>Artemis Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>
            https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-snapshot/
        </url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>



<issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>http://fitdss.ldn.mybankbank.com/jira-agile/browse/IBBC</url>
</issueManagement>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.ldn.mybankbank.com/AA41155-FIT-ARTEMIS/FIT_Artemis/tree/master/Database/</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.ldn.mybankbank.com/AA41155-FIT-ARTEMIS/FIT_Artemis/tree/master/Database</url>
</scm>
```

and setting.xml as

```
<localRepository>/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/maven_repo</localRepository>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>campus-Deploy-Repositories</id>
        <repositories>

            <repository>
                <id>fit-artemis-releases</id>
                <url>https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-release/</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>fit-central</id>
                <url>https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-ccit-shared-001-release/</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>fit-artemis-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-snapshot/</url>
                <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>campus-Deploy-Repositories</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>campus-deploy-central-mirror</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Logs shown below

```
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [Maven Watcher] project started: com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] com.mybank.fit.artemis:database (8s)
[13:36:10]i:         [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:36:10]i:         [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] Surefire report watcher
[13:36:10] :         [Surefire report watcher] Watching paths:
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:36:10]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectStarted tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT' groupId='com.mybank.fit.artemis' artifactId='database' testReportsDir0='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports' testReportsDir1='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports']
[13:36:10] :         [Surefire report watcher] /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:10] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ database ---
[13:36:11] :     [Step 1/2] Surefire report watcher
[13:36:11] :         [Surefire report watcher] Watching paths:
[13:36:11] :         [Surefire report watcher] /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
[13:36:11] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.6/maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
[13:36:12] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloaded from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.6/maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar (13 kB at 30 kB/s)
[13:36:12] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:12] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ database ---
[13:36:13] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.6/maven-project-2.0.6.jar
[13:36:17] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ database ---
[13:36:17] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.jar
[13:36:17] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloaded from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.jar (38 kB at 162 kB/s)

[13:36:18] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Building jar: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar
[13:36:18] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:18] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ database ---
[13:36:18] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Installing /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/artemisd/.m2/repository/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Installing /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/pom.xml to /home/artemisd/.m2/repository/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.pom
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:36:19]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectFinished tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT']
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --------------------< com.mybank.fit.artemis:database >--------------------
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] [Maven Watcher] project started: com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:36:19] :     [Step 1/2] com.mybank.fit.artemis:database (1m:39s)
[13:36:20] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api-2.2.1.jar

[13:36:21] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloaded from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar (49 kB at 68 kB/s)
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) @ database ---
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.tag, **/pom.xml.branch, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.backup
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development && git status --porcelain .
[13:36:22] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development
[13:36:23]W:     [Step 1/2] [WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? Database/development/release.properties
[13:36:23]W:     [Step 1/2] [WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? Database/development/target/
[13:36:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[13:36:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Transforming 'database'...
[13:36:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Not generating release POMs
[13:36:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --------------------< com.mybank.fit.artemis:database >--------------------
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Building database 4.0.98
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] project started: com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98
[13:36:27] :     [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] com.mybank.fit.artemis:database (3s)
[13:36:27]i:[com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:36:27]i:             [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:36:27] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:36:27]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectStarted tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98' groupId='com.mybank.fit.artemis' artifactId='database' testReportsDir0='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports' testReportsDir1='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/surefire-reports']
[13:36:31]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectFinished tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98']
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Total time: 4.808 s
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-03T13:36:31+01:00
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] building report document...
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] building report document done
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] writing report to /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/maven-build-info.xml
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] done writing report
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Transforming 'database'...
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Not removing release POMs
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development && git add -- pom.xml
[13:36:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development
[13:36:32] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[13:36:32] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development
[13:36:32] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development && git status --porcelain .
[13:36:32] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development

[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Release preparation complete.
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] 
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5:perform (default-cli) @ database ---
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Performing a LOCAL checkout from scm:git:file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target && git clone --branch Maven_Released_Database_4.0.98 file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Performing a LOCAL checkout from scm:git:file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target && git clone --branch Maven_Released_Database_4.0.98 file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Performing a LOCAL checkout from scm:git:file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target && git clone --branch Maven_Released_Database_4.0.98 file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0 /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:36:34] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target
[13:37:14] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/temp/buildTmp && git ls-remote file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0
[13:37:14] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/temp/buildTmp
[13:37:15] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout && git fetch file:///sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0
[13:37:15] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:37:15] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout && git checkout Maven_Released_Database_4.0.98
[13:37:15] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:37:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout && git ls-files
[13:37:19] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Working directory: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout
[13:37:20] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development
[13:37:20] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --------------------< com.mybank.fit.artemis:database >--------------------
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] project started: com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT
[13:37:23] :         [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] com.mybank.fit.artemis:database (35s)
[13:37:23]i:             [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] Importing data from '/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[13:37:23]i:             [com.mybank.fit.artemis:database] ##teamcity[importData tc:tags='tc:internal' type='surefire' path='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml' whenNoDataPublished='nothing' logAsInternal='true']
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:37:23]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectStarted tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT' groupId='com.mybank.fit.artemis' artifactId='database' testReportsDir0='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/surefire-reports' testReportsDir1='/sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports']
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] Surefire report watcher
[13:37:23] :         [Surefire report watcher] Watching paths:
[13:37:23] :         [Surefire report watcher] /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
[13:37:23] :     [Step 1/2] Surefire report watcher
[13:37:23] :         [Surefire report watcher] Watching paths:
[13:37:23] :         [Surefire report watcher] /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml
[13:37:24] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:37:24] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ database ---
[13:37:25] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (ANSI_X3.4-1968 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[13:37:25] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/src/main/resources
[13:37:29] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar
[13:37:29] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:37:29] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.1.0:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ database ---
[13:37:42] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/3.0/maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar

[13:37:44] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloaded from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/aether/aether-spi/1.7/aether-spi-1.7.jar (14 kB at 13 kB/s)
[13:37:45] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] No sources in project. Archive not created.
[13:37:45] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:37:45] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ database ---
[13:37:49] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloading from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-30/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-30.jar
[13:37:49] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloaded from mybank-deploy-central-mirror: http://cft-nexus.ldn.mybankbank.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-30/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-30.jar (237 kB at 1.7 MB/s)
[13:37:50] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:37:50] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ database ---
[13:37:51] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Installing /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/artemisd/.m2/repository/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.jar
[13:37:51] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Installing /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/pom.xml to /home/artemisd/.m2/repository/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/database-4.0.98-SNAPSHOT.pom
[13:37:51] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] 
[13:37:51] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ database ---
[13:37:51] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloading from artemis-snapshot-repo: https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-snapshot/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[13:37:52] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Downloaded from artemis-snapshot-repo: https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-snapshot/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (780 B at 991 B/s)
[13:37:52] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Uploading to artemis-snapshot-repo: https://nexus-write.ldn.mybankbank.com/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-oncs-fit-artemis-snapshot/com/mybank/fit/artemis/database/4.0.98-SNAPSHOT/database-4.0.98-20191003.123752-4.jar
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:37:59]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectFinished tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT']
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Total time: 35.816 s
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-03T13:37:59+01:00
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] building report document...
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] building report document done
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] writing report to /sbcimp/dyn/data/fit-artemis/TeamCity/BuildAgent5/work/1d987adac90c8eb0/Database/development/target/checkout/Database/development/target/maven-build-info.xml
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] [Maven Watcher] done writing report
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [Maven Watcher] 
[13:37:59]i:     [Step 1/2] ##teamcity[projectFinished tc:tags='tc:internal' projectId='com.mybank.fit.artemis:database:jar:4.0.98-SNAPSHOT']
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:37:59] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[13:37:59] : Build finished
```

Comment: Change this <version>4.0.98-SNAPSHOT</version> no to your desired version.

Comment: The `install` is not useful. It creates a SNAPSHOT version in local repository. But on your Nexus, you should only get version `4.0.98`, not the SNAPSHOT version. Are you sure you configured you TeamCity correctly?

Comment: @Sambit, Thanks for our response. I believe, Maven should take care of  SNAPSHOT version and push only release version into nexus. Whenever we pull code from GIT, a new snapshot version is created. Even I tried your sugegstion then I am getting below exception:                                           
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project database: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.

Comment: @JFMeier, Thanks for response.Teamcity configuration looks fine to me. Earlier it was working fine with SVN and we have trying to configure it for now with GIT. We are using same configuration for GIT. I have added full logs in detailed section where it was Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT twice then  Building database 4.0.98 and then again  Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT........ but  last building should be  Building database 4.0.98 not  Building database 4.0.98-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

after putting scm plugin in pom.xml , issue has been resolved:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```